# Access a wordpress plugin file globally to receive get/post

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to receive global incoming get/post request on file dashboard.php and i am using the code bellow to add dashboard.php to wordpress menu but problem is i cant access dashboard.php globally i am getting error- 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.' Please advice how can i open dashboard.php for access globally?

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Error: 120' );
/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 **/
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    /**
     * Register a custom menu page.
     */
    function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page() {
        add_menu_page(
            __( 'Amazon Affiliate Dashboard', 'textdomain' ),
            'Amazon Affiliate',
            'manage_options',
            'amazon-affiliate/dashboard.php',
            '',
            plugins_url( 'amazon-affiliate/assets/images/icon2.png' ),
            6
        );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page' );
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discover this message “Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page” mostly occur when various WordPress sites are in the same phpMyAdmin – all bearing the same table prefix, irrespective of the database name. I can’t tell how many WordPress sites are expected to be in the same phpMyAdmin with the same table prefix. Its resolved here http://www.naijatechzone.com/wp-admin-login-error-sorry-you-are-not-allowed-to-access-this-page/

Comment: only single wordpress installed

Comment: Backup your database first.
I can confirm, by renaming the prefix in the DB and in the wp-config.php to wp_TABLENAME, everything is back to normal

Comment: this is not the case at all. its about wordpress auth system. i need some way to pass wp auth and post data on that url